# Is it Considered Bad Practice to Return ResponseEntity with a Message in a Spring Boot REST API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I was wondering if it's bad practice returning a new responseEntity with a string as a message.

For example:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLUFR.png)

If it is bad practice, how would you do it?

Comment: Why not return the saved `Person` as the body?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

`ResponseEntity` represents an HTTP response, including headers, body, and status. While @ResponseBody puts the return value into the body of the response, `ResponseEntity` also allows us to add headers and status codes.

So you can return string but better approach is to wrap it into custom object ane return it.. so in future if you need to return some extra parameter then you can just add into custom object so, no need changes required in return signature of the API

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not bad practice since it offers the flexibility of returning headers and an explicit return status, especially when the status code needs to change depending on some condition.